# Neon lamps in parallel DC

Tags: dc, voltage-divider, negative-resistance

I am making a nixie clock and wanting to use 2 neon lamps in parallel for each colon. However in my test circuit I can only get one to strike at a time.

[image: schematic of test circuit]

The supply voltage is 170Vdc in order to power the nixies elsewhere in the circuit. The two x 10k resistors acting as a voltage divider should provide 85V for each lamp, and the 4K7 resistors should limit the current to an appropriate level once the lamp reach their maintaining voltage (measured at around 72V). However whenever I power up this circuit only one will strike - usually the first though if I disconnect that the other will light up.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neons need more voltage to strike, than to maintain, as you have measured. The first neon to strike will drag down the common terminal to less than the striking voltage for the second.

Ideally reduce the value of the series 10k, and increase the value of the 4.7k resistors.

I wonder why you are using the two 10k resistors at all? Are you trying to switch these in shunt, that is drag the common node down with a transistor to turn the neons off? If so, that is the wrong topology to use, as reducing the series 10k to get both neons on will increase your standing current.

Most people use an NPN switch between ground and one neon pin, with the other tied to a stiff rail through a current limiting resistor. This topology has the added advantage that the switching transistor can be lower voltage than the full rail, as the neon isolates some of the drop.

Answer (score 2):

You want to limit the operating current of a neon bulb to about 1 mA. There's no need for all of those resistors — just connect each one directly to the 170 V rail with its own 100 kΩ resistor.

If you're switching them on and off, as suggested in another answer, 200 V transistors are cheap and common enough; just use an NPN as a low-side switch, between the bulb(s) and ground.

EDIT: You have enough voltage that you could even put the bulbs in series, and use a single 33 kΩ resistor to limit the current to 1 mA.